# Estimate Conditonal Moments from Conditonal Quantiles

Tags: distributions, variance, quantiles, moments, quantile-regression

In Chang et al. ["The Higher Moments of Future Earnings"](http://www.ouazad.com/resources/HigherMoments-CMOV.pdf) (2014), the authors say say that based on (predicted) conditonal quantiles of a variable $y$, one can derive the (predicted) conditional variance of $y$ as follows (A3, page 34):

$$ var(y|\cdot) = \frac{1}{Q}\Sigma_{q\in Q}(quant_q(y|\cdot))^2 - (e(y|\cdot))^2, $$

where $quant_q$ denotes the $q$th of $Q$ evenly distributed quantiles and $e(y|\cdot)$ denotes the average of the $Q$ estimated quantiles. In words: *Average of squared quantiles minus squared average of quantiles equals variance.*

They do not provide a reference and I have not seen this approach in the quantile context before. I tried to find another reference but I could not. Is this a common approach?

Comment: This is a discrete approximation to the usual formula for variance.  In effect, the graph of the (conditional) distribution function $F$ is approximated by a piecewise constant graph whose heights are uniformly spaced among the quantiles.

Comment: I see, and this is non-parametric in the sense that I do not make any assumptions about the distribution, right?

Comment: Close: you implicitly assume the distribution has a finite variance.  But this is still non-parametric, *sort of:* it depends on how those quantiles were predicted.